# Implementing PID in PWM feedback to lower the settling time

Tags: pwm, pid-controller, simulink, closed-loop

I have created the following simple PWM feedback:

[image]

The step response is:
[image]

I have tried to add PID controller and I ran the following code to test it:

```
L = 1.62;
Lp = -1.232;

Kd = Lp/L + 50;
Ki = 1.1;
Kp = Ki/(Kd*L-Lp) + 5;

s = tf('s');
P = L*(Kd*s^2+Kp*s+Ki)/(s^3 + (Kd*L-Lp)*s^2 + L*Kp*s + L*Ki);
step(P)
```

The result was as I wanted:

[image]

However, when I added PID controller to the Simulink simulation It came out like this:

[image]

Is there some way to implement PID at PWM to obtain the desired result (lower settling time and lower overshoot)?

- First I used the PID block right after the Sum block and I got the result above. When moving the PID block right before the Abs block (after the split to the sign block) the results were better but still not as the step response.
- After running many tests it seems like it takes the respond around 1 sec to get to value 0.5 and it is like a limit that doesnt change no matter what values were taken into the PID.

Thank you.

Comment: Try doing your simulation for a longer interval.  Do 50 seconds, or 200 or something.

Comment: But I want my settling time to be like in the step response I showed, less than 0.3 seconds at least. Why would I care what happen after 15 seconds?

Comment: to figure out what is wrong. Step back and stop thinking "it should end here" when it clearly doesn't.  Look at what it actually is doing. Run it for 50seconds and see when it settles out and then you will see you have a factor of 100 or so somewhere.  The present plot clearly hasn't even reached it peak so how can you hope to understand where the problem is if you don't fully know what it presently is doing. This is diagnostics 101

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. What's your plant? Why didn't you build your controller as C = pid(Kp,Ki,Kd)? Then let matlab calculate closed loop response. Where did you get that equation?

Comment: That equation is just PID*Plant/(1+PID*Plant), like closed loop of the system with PID

Comment: What is your question? is it why adding an overcompensated inner loop to an undercompensated outer loop results in a more undercompensated total loop?

Comment: No, my question is why when implementing PID with plant when using result system, the result is different than using the same PID and implementing it with pwm and how do I fix it to be like when it was without the pwm

Comment: This is really confusing. If the only difference is PWM being added then there’s something wrong with the PWM design - number of bits and/or frequency.

Comment: @Ben fair enough I just trust Matlab more than my own algebraic skills. H = P*C/(1+P*C) is easier for me. I would start by studying your design as a discrete time system below the PWM frequency then move to PWM.

Comment: @Ben - Be careful using * in equations (in questions and comments). As you can see in one of your recent comments, the * characters have been recognised as Markdown syntax (which they are) to switch to Italics and so the * characters themselves have disappeared from the formulas :-(. In future, the simplest solutions are to either use MathJAX syntax or, when not using MathJAX, put a space either side of each * character, or use `monospace format` delimited with the ` character. Hope that helps.